# ORA-12514 error listener I can't connect to my oracle db

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm unable to explain anything as I don't know much about databases nor do I wish to learn because I hate that, with that said, I'm trying to connect to my oracle db, I'm quite sure that the port is 1522, the SID is surely orcl and the global name is orcl.station, I tought the service name was also orcl.station but this error is telling me that it doesn't know that service so idk

this is my listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle_home\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_BOH NOME LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle_home\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
  )

FORTUNATO =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-VVEP6NE.station)(PORT = 1522))
    )
  )

BOH NOME LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-VVEP6NE.station)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

my listener should be fortunato

and here's mt tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle_home\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-VVEP6NE.station)(PORT = 1522))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-VVEP6NE.station)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = SHARED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.station)
    )
  )
```

please tell me what to do in order to make this thing work i need it badly

Comment: if you run lsnrctl from command line, and enter "status" what do you see?

Comment: Connection to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521)) -->wrong port
TNS-12541: TNS: nessun listener -->no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS: errore dell'adattatore del protocollo -->error of protocol's adaptor
  TNS-00511: Nessun listener --> no listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error

Comment: sounds like your listener and/or database isn't running - check Windows service manager

Comment: @thatjeffsmith just checked, they are running, except 1 listener on the default port but that's not where my db runs

Comment: _"1 listener on the default port but that's not where my db runs"_  The database doesn't run "on a port" at all.  That default port of 1521 is used by the listener only.  It is the port where clients direct their initial request to the listener.  The database knows nothing about it.   As for your comment " nor do I wish to learn", then you are in the wrong business.

Comment: Why are you defining two listeners?  Why not a single listener?  Why not run that single listener on the default port of 1521, and allow the database, by default, to register itself with that listener on the default port?  I'd get rid of the listener.ora file completely, restart the listener (default name LISTENER) which, wihtout a listener.ora, will come up with all default values and almost certainly be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: @EdStevens look, I'm just really frustrated because this thing has to be solved by tomorrow, ive been working for 2 weeks straight weekends incuded to finish a webapp, now im done, I move the project to the laptop to bring it at the office and oracle decides once again to be a pain in the back, right now my only concern is to make this thing work.

Comment: because when oracle was creating the db the first time it got an error and it interrupted, but the listener was already there on that port, so I had to do it again and oracle felt like making it work this time, I had to put it on another port because the default one was already in use, so btw you're telling me that if Idelete the listener.ora file and restart the other listener on 1521 the connection to the db will work? if so I have to tell you that if i restart that other listener on the services windows thing it tells me that it started and istantly stopped

Comment: Delete the listenr.ora file.  Delete both listener services.  (That's a windows issue).  Logged on as the owner of the oracle installation, open a cmd prompt with admin priv, and execute 'lsnrctl start'.  That will recreate a listener with all defaults, including running on the default port of 1521.  May not solve all of your issues,, but it will most certainly simplify the landscape, making further troubleshooting easier.